# Powering a notebook directly from a 24 V power supply

Tags: power-supply

SWMBO and I are currently in the design phase of our "rest of life" camper truck. It will probably have 6 x 350 W (at least) solar panels, controller, etc., all feeding a pair of 24 V lithium-ion (or by then perhaps lithium-sulphur or metal-air) rack batteries. A 24 V ring will run around the truck living space for all devices and electrical items and we plan to use USB lights which can be plugged in wherever we need light.

We are trying to limit the use of an inverter as much as possible, hence the following question. Can I power an older Dell notebook that requires (according to the now dead PSU) 19.1 V directly from a 24 V power supply? If I can, do I need to use any kind of filtering or anything additional?

Comment: Filters are good, but what you need is almost only a 24v to 19.1v buck power supply of about 100w, so something like 6A. Note that applying voltage may not be enough - sometimes it takes a resistor on the third line or even some sort of one wire communication. Take a compatible charger and see what's there.

Comment: And yeah, my own SWMBO didn't like the term

Comment: What does SWMBO mean?

Comment: She Who Must Be Obeyed. Just googled it now 

Comment: SWMBO == "She Who Must Be Obeyed"

Comment: @PitchforkGuy it's best if you find something off-the-shelf. If you need to design it, let me know, I'll help. But maybe in fact even 24V can work. It's not going directly to the battery, and i find it really hard to believe that there are parts that would suffer from extra 5V. That might be a good topic to search on Google or experiment with. And one other way is to find a car charger. This one also might work with 24v, but if not, you will find it much easier to step down 24 to 12, than to 19 with off-the-shelf devices.

Comment: (Always *SWAMBO* for ease of pronunciation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome on board (building a camper). 24V power bus is good (unlike 12V).

While using a small, simple and cheap buck converter to power a laptop off 24V grid is certainly possible, I would recommend somewhat more fail-safe and future-proof approach.

1. Get a powerful USB-PD car charger. E.g. [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085YGJXZR). Be sure that its USB-PD output is powerful enough for your laptop, see watt (W) rating.
2. Get an USB-C to your computer adapter, e.g. [like this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/334635655268)

Why such a simple adapter is possible? USB-PD devices negotiate their voltage. In the adapter, a very small and simple chip talks to the USB-PD power source "I need 20V" and the power source does whatever asked. Devices that are designed to use USB-PD do that themselves.

Advantages:

- Single, factory-built adapter for all your battery-powered electronics (phones, tablets, photo cameras (see below), etc... If it breaks, you get a compatible one from wherever you find it and not necessarily from a DELL vendor.
- USB-PD to DELL adapters are cheap (~$10). You can get few of them if your old computer is of particular importance.
- Future-proof: whatever new computer you are going to buy, chances are it will be USB-PD powered. Same goes for phones, tablets, photo cameras, pocket torches, power toothbrushes, power tools and whatever else has a battery and is small enough.
- The USB-PD chargers are generally quite power efficient (otherwise they would overheat in the lighter socket).

---

In a lot of big markets (e.g. EU and China following) USB-PD power input is mandatory on all phones and tablets (now), laptops (from 2024 on), photo cameras (don't remember), etc...

Chances are in a year or two all new laptops all over the world will be USB-PD powered.

Comment: Since you accepted my answer, I assume you are going to implement the idea. Please, pay attention to the variety of DELL power plugs. All of them exist as USB-PD adapters, just take care to get the right one. Voltage variety is of less importance - they are labeled 19.0 or 19.5 or 20.0 V and these are all the same - the voltage is as much near 20.0 V as some obscure regulation allows.

Answer (score 1):

"24V" lithium-ion  batteries are going to provide between
25.2 and 22.5 volts assuming you don't flog them too hard, so some sort of buck converter can be used to provide 19.1V

Laptop charging tends to want about 100W (but check the label on your power supply for the output current) a 5A buck module will get you 95.5W

Adjustable buck modules are easily had from pretty much any online marketplace, but they tend to over-claim and under deliver on power handling, so I'd be looking for a 8A or 10A capable module if going this cheaper route.

Else buy a manufactured laptop car/truck charger, one that says "24v" or "12-24" input should be fine. Ten times the price but none of the DIY hassle.  Searching for "laptop truck charger" should get you some good results.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work.

You can't feed 24V into 19.1V device unless it is within a known range, and the range is unknown.

Even if you had a DC/DC converter which will convert 24V to 19.1V, it still would not work.

The power supply needs to communicate with the laptop somehow that how much current is available for the laptop to draw only the amount available. If you don't know how the laptop and supply communicates, laptop will not charge as it does not how much it can draw.

Now, havig said that, laptops have car chargers, buy one that works with your voltage input and with your laptop.